# List index out of range error in object detection using YoloV3 in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to implement Object Detection using YOLOV3 AND Pytorch. I am training the model on my custom Dataset, which contains 200 images of one type only and has only one object (which is labelled, for ref. check the image below). I have annotated the Images and saved them into .txt format.

*Dataset*

--------*images*
         img1.jpg
         img2.jpg

--------*labels*
         img1.txt
         img2.txt

test.txt
valid.txt

My model training part is working fine. I save weights, after every epoch(Checkpoints). I run the program(training part) for 20 Epoch values and take the last saved checkpoint weight for the object detection part.
There is only 1 class (IRA), indexed (0)
My Yolo.cfg file is also correct. [class = 1, filters = 18] (updated in three parts of the file)

But the problem is:- 
On running the object detection part of the program, I am getting this error
[image: as you can see I am not getting the label but it is detecting the object in the correct part of the image]

This problem is specific to this only. I tested on other images dataset, it worked fine but I don't know why it is not giving any label in this case?

**Here is my training model part**

```
 from __future__ import division

from models import *
from utils import *
from datasets import *
from parse_config import *

import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import argparse

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f")
parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=20, help="number of epochs")
parser.add_argument("--image_folder", type=str, default="/content/drive/My Drive/FINAL_PYTORCH_DATA/images", help="path to dataset")
parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=16, help="size of each image batch")
parser.add_argument("--model_config_path", type=str, default="/content/drive/My Drive/config/yolov3.cfg", help="path to model config file")
parser.add_argument("--data_config_path", type=str, default="/content/drive/My Drive/config/coco.data", help="path to data config file")
parser.add_argument("--weights_path", type=str, default="/content/drive/My Drive/config/yolov3.weights", help="path to weights file")
parser.add_argument("--class_path", type=str, default="/content/drive/My Drive/config/coco.names", help="path to class label file")
parser.add_argument("--conf_thres", type=float, default=0.8, help="object confidence threshold")
parser.add_argument("--nms_thres", type=float, default=0.4, help="iou thresshold for non-maximum suppression")
parser.add_argument("--n_cpu", type=int, default=0, help="number of cpu threads to use during batch generation")
parser.add_argument("--img_size", type=int, default=416, help="size of each image dimension")
parser.add_argument("--checkpoint_interval", type=int, default=1, help="interval between saving model weights")
parser.add_argument("--checkpoint_dir", type=str, default="/content/checkpoints", help="directory where model checkpoints are saved")
parser.add_argument("--use_cuda", type=bool, default=True, help="whether to use cuda if available")
opt = parser.parse_args()
print(opt)

cuda = torch.cuda.is_available() and opt.use_cuda

os.makedirs("checkpoints", exist_ok=True)

classes = load_classes(opt.class_path)

# Get data configuration
data_config = parse_data_config(opt.data_config_path)
train_path = data_config["train"]

# Get hyper parameters
hyperparams = parse_model_config(opt.model_config_path)[0]
learning_rate = float(hyperparams["learning_rate"])
momentum = float(hyperparams["momentum"])
decay = float(hyperparams["decay"])
burn_in = int(hyperparams["burn_in"])

# Initiate model
model = Darknet(opt.model_config_path)
model.load_weights(opt.weights_path)
#model.apply(weights_init_normal)

if cuda:
    model = model.cuda()

model.train()

# Get dataloader
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    ListDataset(train_path), batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=opt.n_cpu
)

Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if cuda else torch.FloatTensor

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()))

for epoch in range(opt.epochs):
    for batch_i, (_, imgs, targets) in enumerate(dataloader):
        imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor))
        targets = Variable(targets.type(Tensor), requires_grad=False)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss = model(imgs, targets)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print(
            "[Epoch %d/%d, Batch %d/%d] [Losses: x %f, y %f, w %f, h %f, conf %f, cls %f, total %f, recall: %.5f, precision: %.5f]"
            % (
                epoch,
                opt.epochs,
                batch_i,
                len(dataloader),
                model.losses["x"],
                model.losses["y"],
                model.losses["w"],
                model.losses["h"],
                model.losses["conf"],
                model.losses["cls"],
                loss.item(),
                model.losses["recall"],
                model.losses["precision"],
            )
        )

        model.seen += imgs.size(0)

    if epoch % opt.checkpoint_interval == 0:
        model.save_weights("%s%d.weights" % (opt.checkpoint_dir, epoch))
```

**Here is my model loading part:-**

```
config_path='/content/drive/My Drive/config/yolov3.cfg'
weights_path='/content/checkpoints19.weights'
class_path='/content/drive/My Drive/config/coco.names'
img_size=416
conf_thres=0.8
nms_thres=0.4

# Load model and weights
model = Darknet(config_path, img_size=img_size)
model.load_weights(weights_path)
model.cuda()
model.eval()
classes = utils.load_classes(class_path)
Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
```

**Here is my object detection part:-**

```
def detect_image(img):
    # scale and pad image
    ratio = min(img_size/img.size[0], img_size/img.size[1])
    imw = round(img.size[0] * ratio)
    imh = round(img.size[1] * ratio)
    img_transforms = transforms.Compose([ transforms.Resize((imh, imw)),
         transforms.Pad((max(int((imh-imw)/2),0), max(int((imw-imh)/2),0), max(int((imh-imw)/2),0), max(int((imw-imh)/2),0)),
                        (128,128,128)),
         transforms.ToTensor(),
         ])
    # convert image to Tensor
    image_tensor = img_transforms(img).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    input_img = Variable(image_tensor.type(Tensor))
    # run inference on the model and get detections
    with torch.no_grad():
        detections = model(input_img)
        detections = utils.non_max_suppression(detections, 80, conf_thres, nms_thres)
    return detections[0]

# load image and get detections
img_path = "/content/image1 - Copy (2).jpg"
prev_time = time.time()
img = Image.open(img_path)
detections = detect_image(img)
inference_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time() - prev_time)
print ('Inference Time: %s' % (inference_time))

# Get bounding-box colors
cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20b')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 20)]

img = np.array(img)
plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,9))
ax.imshow(img)

pad_x = max(img.shape[0] - img.shape[1], 0) * (img_size / max(img.shape))
pad_y = max(img.shape[1] - img.shape[0], 0) * (img_size / max(img.shape))
unpad_h = img_size - pad_y
unpad_w = img_size - pad_x
k=[]
if detections is not None:
    unique_labels = detections[:, -1].cpu().unique()
    n_cls_preds = len(unique_labels)
    bbox_colors = random.sample(colors, n_cls_preds)
    # browse detections and draw bounding boxes
    for x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, cls_conf, cls_pred in detections:
        box_h = ((y2 - y1) / unpad_h) * img.shape[0]
        box_w = ((x2 - x1) / unpad_w) * img.shape[1]
        y1 = ((y1 - pad_y // 2) / unpad_h) * img.shape[0]
        x1 = ((x1 - pad_x // 2) / unpad_w) * img.shape[1]
        color = bbox_colors[int(np.where(unique_labels == int(cls_pred))[0])]
        bbox = patches.Rectangle((x1, y1), box_w, box_h, linewidth=2, edgecolor=color, facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(bbox)
        k=classes[int(cls_pred)]
        plt.text(x1, y1, s=classes[int(cls_pred)], color='white', verticalalignment='top',
                bbox={'color': color, 'pad': 0})
plt.axis('off')
# save image
plt.savefig(img_path.replace(".jpg", "-det.jpg"), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
plt.show()
print(k)
```

If anyone can help me understand, what causes this error and how to solve this?

Comment: You are getting an index out of range error on a line where you try to index your class list. `k=classes[int(cls_pred)]`. Add a breakpoint, check that your cls_pred isn't larger than the dimention of classes.

Comment: Hey @Cecilia, can you be more specific with the solution. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Index out of range error means that your index, cls_pred, is larger than len(classes). You need to diagnose why that is happening. I recommend a breakpoint at that line or shortly before that line and then examining both values to see what went wrong.

Comment: Hey @Cecilia, I tried as you said, and I found out these two things:-
1) cls_pred value is 0.
2) len(classes) value is 0
can you please further help me with this. Tx

Comment: Hey, @Cecilia Issue is resolved now. Tx :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can happen too when you are using a single image on training and validation. If you want to detect Apples but you train your model on a single picture containing 200 apples for example...

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem then it is probably because there is no extra line in the coco.names files after the last element.
Make sure there is always one extra line(blank) after the last element.
Otherwise, it will throw an error as a **`List index out of range.`**